# Shorten php if var use var

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code tastes quite repetitive, can I avoid to repeat the userdata function call ?

```
if($this->session->userdata('lang'))
        $lang = $this->session->userdata('lang');
```

Comment: `if($lang = $this->session->userdata('lang')){}`

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè and if I don't want to replace `$lang` if it's false…?

Comment: `$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang') ?: $lang;` But come on, this is just nit-picking. Write the `if` block once and then forget about it.

Comment: Shouldn't the solution have $lang unset when false too?

Comment: What is the `else` supposed to be here...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHP >= 5.3 you can just do:

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang') ?: '';
```

Comment: `$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang') ?: $lang;` I think? (and is as of PHP 5.3)

Comment: This'd work, as long as the return value of the call isn't a "falsey" type value. e.g. if it legitimately returns (say) a `0`, the zero would now get replaced with an empty string.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. No garbage variable, clear and concise. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Store the result in a temporary variable:

```
if($temp = $this->session->userdata('lang'))
        $lang = $temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the source](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Session/Session.php#L246), the method returns NULL if the value is not found, so your if statement (as it currently stands) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang')?$this->session->userdata('lang'):"";
```

but as @bwoebi points out this does not avoid doubling down on the function call.

You can create a function to do the dirty work for you.

```
function getValueOrDefault($value, $default = null){
      return $value?$value:$default;
}
$lang = getValueOrDefault($this->session->userdata('lang'), "en");
```

or for your case depending on what a false return of $this->session->userdata() is this

```
$lang = $this->session->userdata('lang');
```

may be an equivalent.

Comment: this is not an answer: you repeat the function call. question was: `can I avoid to repeat the userdata function call`